# Google Analytics Events No Longer Working In Universal Analytics & GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I had a script using the older Google Analytics tag that was directly embeded on my page. This script fired an event when it detected that ad block was being used:

```
    <!--AB Check--> 
    <script type = "text/javascript"
    src = "http://example.com/JS/Ads3.js"> </script>  

    <script type = "text/javascript" > jQuery(document).ready(checkAds());

    function checkAds() {
        if (document.getElementById('adsense') != undefined) {
            document.write("<script>_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Adblock', 'Unblocked', 'false',,true]);</sc" + "ript>");
        } else {
            document.write("<script>_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Adblock', 'Blocked', 'true',,true]);</sc" + "ript>");
        }
    } </script>
    <!--End AB Check-->
```

Recently I moved my Google Analytics tag to Universal Analytics and Google Tag Manager. At that time my script broke and no longer records these events.

How can I update my adblock script to be compatible with Universal Analytics and GTM?

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't using GTM, then you need to change the event tracking code to use the `ga` function:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Adblock', 'Unblocked', 'false', {nonInteraction: true});
ga('send', 'event', 'Adblock', 'Blocked', 'true', {nonInteraction: true});
```

More information about this event tracking code can be found here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

But since you are using GTM, what you could do is to create your event tag that is fired via custom JS trigger that returns a boolean, depending on the conditions for checking the `adSense` ID.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately using the ga function is not an option with GTM. I've had to go the other route - I'm going to submit that best explains what I ended up doing in GTM.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this article http://dcarlbom.com/google-tag-manager/measure-how-many-of-your-visitors-that-are-using-adblock to set the event tracking up for GTM.

Thanks @nyuen for explaining how to do this using the `ga` function, but unfortunately this won't work for folks using GTM.